# Laravel Model not returning properties with default value after creation

Tags: php, laravel

In my controller after I create a new Post I return the new post in a post variable. For some reason I don't get the properties with default values back. I noticed that if I set the value to something in controller it does indeed return the properties in the payload.

```php
public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate(PostValidator::$create);

        $post = new Post();
        $post->postcategory_id = $request->input('postcategoryid');
        $post->user_id = $request->input('authorid');
        $post->thumbnail = $this->uploadFile($request, 'thumbnail', config('app.defaultImage'));
        $post->video = $request->input('video');
        $post->slug = $this->slugify($request->input('title'));
        $post->url = '/publicaciones/'.$this->slugify($request->input('title'));
        $post->title = $request->input('title');
        $post->body = $request->input('body');
        $post->isVisible = false; //IF I DO THIS isVisible is returned in $post variable
        $post->save();

        $post->load(['postcategory','author']);

        return response()->json([
            'post' => $post,
        ]);

    }
```

Comment: Show your migration and your `$visible` and `$hidden` attributes in the model, and also show the `json response` from this

Comment: What's the use of `$validatedData` if you don't use it anywhere?

Answer (score 11):

you can say laravel works like that. default values defined in the database layer is absent in a newly created object. however you can use [`refresh`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-models) to refresh the object before returning. and it will have the missing values then.

```
$post = new Post();
$post->attribute = $request->attribute;
$post->save();

$post = $post->refresh();
return $post;
```

or you can set default values in the model layer

```
protected $attributes = [
   'isVisible' => false
];
```

and you will have the default values when returning a newly created object.

Comment: I had the same problem, I set the default values, but it worked like so:

protected $attributes = [
        'isVisible' => false,
    ];